# In a mixed-cabin scenario, do benefits apply on other legs?

Tags: air-travel, air-canada

For an Air Canada itinerary "mixed cabin" scenario, where the 1st and 2nd legs are in Economy but the third leg is in premium economy, do the premium economy checkin benefits apply when checking in prior to the first leg?

Comment: Are you sure there are any check-in benefits? I don't think I've ever seen a special check-in counter for Premium Economy. It certainly makes no difference when you check in online :-)

Comment: @Hilmar Most airlines give free/more bags with Premium Economy, for example, which I guess could be considered a "checkin benefit"

Comment: @Hilmar Maybe the benefit is seat selection.

Comment: @Hilmar priority boarding, extra bags I'm guessing. Not sure I'd call them checkin benefits, but definitely benefits

Comment: @beeonrope are these all on one ticket and is the premium economy an international leg? And were you given the opportunity/option to get premium economy on the other legs?

Comment: @Hilmar Singapore Airlines has dedicated checkin counters for Premium Economy, I'm sure there are others too.

Comment: @Midavalo - yes, premium economy is an international leg, the one one of the 3 legs that is international. No opportunity on other legs.

Comment: Usually you get the benefits of the most significant leg, but I can’t find any information on this topic on the Air Canada website. Also some benefits just may not be available in some smaller airports or on smaller aircraft.

Comment: It would help if you specify what the benefits are you think you're entitled to. It wouldn't make much sense to have a lower checked baggage allowance on some legs of the journey. But as others have said if you're flying connecting flights to/from regional airports, there may not be any benefits on those flights either at the regional airport or on the plane.